# Setting Custom Field on new BAccount Object

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to set a custom field on a brand new BAccount object created via the action ConvertToBAccount() in the Contact BLC. I've tried quite a few different things including overriding the action and trying to set the value on the object after the action is complete and navigates to the BAccount BLC. I found that I can't set the value on the override because there is no record in the database until the user manually saves, and when I try to set the value after the action, it sets the field, but does not show the new value on the screen when the BAccount BLC is done loading.

How can I set an extension field for a new BAccount created via the ConvertToBAccount() action on the Contacts BLC?

DAC Extension:

```
public class BAccountExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount>
{
        #region UsrHomeCampus
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Home Campus")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PX.Objects.GL.Branch.branchID>),
        typeof(PX.Objects.GL.Branch.branchCD),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(PX.Objects.GL.Branch.branchCD))]
        public virtual int? UsrHomeCampus { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrHomeCampus : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
}
```

BLC Code:

```
public class BusinessAccountMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<BusinessAccountMaint>
{
    #region Event Handlers
    protected void Contact_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contact row = (Contact)e.Row;

        if (row.ContactID > 0 && Base.CurrentBAccount.Current.BAccountID < 0)
        {
            Base.CurrentBAccount.Current.GetExtension<BAccountExt>().UsrHomeCampus = row.GetExtension<ContactExt>().UsrHomeCampus;
            //Save record in database
            Base.Actions.PressSave();
            //Cause page refresh
            Base.Actions.PressCancel();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the full exception with Stack Trace.

Comment: I don't get any exception, it just doesn't set a value to the extension field. The segment I showed was just from the Watch window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Your Dac Extension is for BAccount or Contact? Your view's name is CurrentBAccount but Dac Extension is ContactExt

Comment: It is for BAccount. Thank you for catching that. I will correct it above, but the situation remains. It does set the value, but it does not display the value I set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a `BAccount` is being created from Contact by `ConvertToBAccount()` method the `BAccountID` of the newly created `BAccount` is being set to `Contact`'s `BAccountID` field.

You should take that BAccount for example by querying something like this

```
BAccount bAccount = PXSelect<BAccount,Where<BAccount.bAccountID,Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>.Select(graph,contactObject.BAccountID);
```

Then get you extension like this:

```
BAccountExt acc = PXCache<BAccount>.GetExtension<BAccountExt>(bAccount);
```

And set the values that you need and then update the BAccount in some way like this:

```
this.Base.BAccountsView.Update(bAccount);
this.Base.Save.Press();
```

Comment: Fundamentally, Acumatica forces the user to save the record manually. If I automate this process, do you know of any consequences this might cause?

Comment: I implemented your solution and even with the automated save, it is not showing the value still. I'm not sure if the fact the field is a selector would make a difference. Also the field is not marked for commit changes.

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution above, but it doesn't seem to work. The Contact.BAccountID is coming back as -2147483647.

Comment: @EricP. Add the source of the Dac extension and your change in the BLC I will take a look and answer

Comment: I added the code. Currently the value is being set the way I'm doing it, but the new value is not showing on the screen unless I refresh the page with the browser.

Comment: @EricP. try use `Base.CurrentBAccount.View.RequestRefresh()` instead of `Cancel` button.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply on this. I can't remember what I did, but I believe I found I had messed something up that was preventing the program from giving me the desired result. What you have above should also perform the action correctly. I will mark this as accepted answer.